# How to return the line number of a line being read from a text file?

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file (`my_file.txt`) as follows:

> Game of Thrones
>
> Friends
>
> Suits
>
> Hospital Playlist

From this file, I need to choose a random line & return it along with the line number.

For returning a random line, I do:

```
lines = open('my_file.txt').read().splitlines()
my_random_line = random.choice(lines)
```

But how can I get the info about the line number of the line?

**Example:**

If the line returned is `Suits`, the number of the line should be: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of choosing a random line, choose a random number that is within the number of lines.  Then return that number and that line.

```
lines = myfile.readlines()
choice = random.randint(len(lines) - 1)
return choice, lines[choice]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the line number randomly, then use it as an index to get the line:

```
#random integer from 1 to lenth of lines (both inclusive)
line_number = random.randint(1, len(lines))
#subtract one because lists are 0-indexed
my_random_line = lines[line_number-1]
```